# No wubildr, No spaceleft, Boot Error and A previous installation was detected in D:\ubuntu. Please uninstall that before continuing

Tags: wubi, boot-failure

At first I was downloading Ubuntu 12.10 using Windows Installer, but I cancelled it after just 2-3 minutes and downloaded 32-Bit ISO (ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386).

Then I created bootable USB Stick (new HP 210 v210 w) using Pendrivelinux
(Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.1.4).

- I Formatted D Drive. (Both by Windows & EaseUS)
- I've set boot priority correctly.

But after getting message

"Boot Error":

- I ran wubi.exe directly from USB drive.

Now the message is

"A previous installation was detected in D:\ubuntu. Please uninstall that before continuing."

- I formatted D: again and performed disk check, surface test using EaseUS. It shows no error or bad sectors.
- Formatted & checked my pendrive too.
- Directly ran .iso.

But same error keeps coming.

I found way around above problems, by copying extracted .iso on D:\ and installing Ubuntu using wubi.exe and though on boot it was shown with Windows 7, selecting it caused following error:

- `Try hd(0,0): NTFS5 : No wubildr
  Try hd(0,1): NTFS5 :`

So, I uninstalled it and reinstalled it

- Now installation fails at around 7mins saying

  `An error occurred.
  No space left on device.
  For more info please see log file`

My D: is a 9 GB partition. (99% Free)

Ubuntu Site 12.10 says it needs around 4.5 GB.

- Now trying it by extendin D: to 10 GB...
- Got No wubildr.

Comment: It seems like you have a number of issues. First is booting Ubuntu from a USB. Second is installing with Wubi from USB. Third installing Wubi with ISO together. Fourth is Wubi's grub4dos not finding wubildr. Fifth installing when \ubuntu exists. Sixth installing without enough free space. Seventh, back to the wubildr problem. I recommend identifying clearly what you want answered.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Last thing I tried is to install it on formatted pendrive through wubi. It took around 9.16 GB. But on boot wubildr isn't found. I checked from bcdedit the partition and wubildr address. They are fine. (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20340/how-to-restore-the-wubi-ubuntu-bootloader/). I've a i386 iso, a 16 GB pendrive (my dvd/cd drives don't work) and a 10 GB Partition. My 32-bit PC is Pentium 4 2.4 Ghz, 1 GB RAM with Windows 7 on the other 30 GB partition. I'm first timer at Linux. With the resources stated above tell me how to run Ubuntu. Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my advice:
Either run `wubi.exe` standalone or
Dowload the desktop ISO, save it in the same folder as `wubi.exe`, make sure they're from the same release, and run Wubi.

Do not install Wubi from CD or USB - *or even have an Ubuntu CD or USB inserted in your computer* (it will find them and use them). The former needs a workaround, and the last time I tried the latter, it tried to copy the entire USB partition as the ISO and that can be 2-16GB.

If you see:

```
Try hd(0,0): NTFS5 : No wubildr 
Try hd(0,1): NTFS5 :
```

This means that wubi can read the first partition hd(0,0) (= /dev/sda1) and there is no wubildr there (which is normal if it's a recovery or boot partition). And it means that wubi is hanging when attempting to read the second partition hd(0,1) (= /dev/sda2). I don't know why, but it does that sometimes - rarely. If I were you, I'd boot from that USB you have, mount /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda1 and copy /wubildr to it.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sda2
sudo mkdir /mnt/sda1
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
sudo cp /mnt/sda2/wubildr /mnt/sda1/wubildr
sudo umount /mnt/sda2
sudo umount /mnt/sda1
sudo rmdir /mnt/sda2
sudo rmdir /mnt/sda1
```

That should get wubildr (grub2) going.

If you have a spare paritition (`D:`) then I would actually recommend just installing directly to it, rather than use Wubi. It's much better, if you can handle Ubuntu being in control of your boot process (make a windows repair cd before so you can replace the windows bootloader if you want to uninstall later). But if you have to use Wubi then you can use the above techniques.

Comment: First of all thanks for responding so quickly. I tried once again as you suggested: 1. Formatted D:\. 2. Copied Wubi & ISO to it. 3. Removed USB. 4. Ran Wubi with internet connected.* it installed under 5.5 GB 5. Checked bcdedit. 6. Reboot. Result: Try hd (same as you mentioned)  Then I made USB from UNetbootin & opted for boot from USB. Result: A disk read error has occurred. USB made from Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.1.4 gives same or simply "Boot Error" if I recall exactly. Should I try 12.04 or 12.10 LTS? I can't remove Windows at present. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: I will also try wubi standalone later as I've exhausted my internet data pack so speed is too slow. Thanks

Comment: You should run an MD5 check on the ISO you're using to create the USB. It's probably invalid if you're getting boot errors: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows

Comment: Thanksagain.Just checked MD5 with "winMD5Sum" and "Checksums calculator".Both found it identical with official one.BTW wubi-12.10-rev273 log says:`11-03 05:17 ERROR  CommonBackend: The md5 of the metalink does match
11-03 05:17 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot authenticate the metalink file, it might be corrupt
None
11-03 05:17 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_metalink
11-03 05:17 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_file_md5
11-03 05:17 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_file_md5...
11-03 05:17 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_file_md5
11-03 05:17 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso.`Normal?

Comment: That says that the metalink is corrupted. So no, it's not normal. It means that it had to skip the MD5 check on the ISO so it's not conclusive that the ISO is corrupt as well. Since you manually checked the ISO, you know it's good. But since you can't boot from the USB, maybe there was a problem creating it. Did you use the instructions here?: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows Just trying to figure out why you can't boot from it.

Comment: I'd followed it earlier but did it again on your suggestion. Have used UNetbootin, Universal-USB-Installer which gave **Boot Error** and finally LiLi Creator. It gave **Boot Error** too but when I ran Virtual Box created by it, it said:<br/>  **This kernel requires following features not present on this CPU: pae  **<br/>  **Unable to boot. Please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.**<br/>

Comment: I checked that my cpu supports **PAE** from Coreinfo [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx] and then set **DEP** to **AlwaysOff**, **PAE** to **ForceEnable**:  [http://www.smartsoftwarebits.com/qaa/46-misc/84-how-to-enable-pae-for-windows7-x86] and  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542275.aspx].  Then I recreated the USB. SAME ERROR. Additionally to remove 1 potential error source (USB) I copied wubi and iso to D:\ and reinstalled it there. **Try hd**, as earlier. Thanks for responding.

Comment: And one more thing. I don't Know whether this matters or not. I had downloaded Wubi on My PC but as I was facing problems with my UPS Power Backup, I downloaded i386 ISO on a 64-bit Intel Core-i3 Dell Laptop. From there I copied it through an external HD to my PC. Just to let you know. Thanks.

Comment: That's a bit odd... not working in the VM. I know Canonical stopped shipping a non-pae kernel in 12.10. Why don't you try 12.04.1 and see what happens there. But the wubildr issue will be the same unless you copy it to /dev/sda1.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to thank you for all the help you provided. Though I couldn't run Ubuntu I learned may new things. So Thank You. I'll post any positive or valuable development.